# What's the difference between function and => in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Currently, I am learning TypeScript. I am quite confused about the difference between keyword function and => (fat arrow). Please see the code below:

```
interface Counter {
    (start: number);
    interval: number;
    reset() : void;
}

let a = <Counter>function(start: number) { };
let b = <Counter>(start: number) => { };

a.reset(); //OK
b.reset(); //error: Property 'reset' does not exist on type <Counter>(start: number) => void
```

It seems that fat arrow doesn't work the same as keyword function.

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript. It is purely a JS (ES6) issue. The difference is well explained in hundreds of blog posts, documentation pages, and questions right here on SO.

Comment: @torazaburo Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

fat arrow functions have a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically bind the this value. Arrow functions are always anonymous and effectively turn `function (arguments) { return expression; }` into `(arguments) => expression`. If using an expression after an arrow, the return is implicit, so no return is required.

Comment: The term "fat arrow function" is obsolete. The correct term is "arrow function".

Answer (score 2):

It's all about keeping the context/scope in JavaScript. Take a look here: [What is this in JavaScript and Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#what-is-this-in-javascript).