# Typescript function() vs () => in angular

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between

```
function {}
```

And

```
() => {}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you search for `Is there a difference betweenfunction {} and () => {}` you will get [What's the difference between function and => in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115464) as top match.